# How to setup sorbet to work with a Rails 7 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

note: I'm not using and I want to know if it is possible without `sorbet-rails`.

I'm trying to add sorbet to an existing/standard Rails 7 application.

I followed the instruction here: https://sorbet.org/docs/adopting.

I added the gems to the Gemfile followed by `bundle install`.

```
gem 'sorbet', :group => :development
gem 'sorbet-runtime'
gem 'tapioca', require: false, :group => :development
```

After that:

```
bundle exec tapioca init
bin/tapioca dsl
bin/tapioca gem
bin/tapioca require
bin/tapioca gem --all
bin/tapioca annotations
```

After running all that, if I ran `bundle exec srb tc`, I get about 23 errors. Most of them related to generated rbi files. For exemple:

```
...
sorbet/rbi/dsl/sessions_controller.rbi:19: Unable to resolve constant ActionHelper https://srb.help/5002
    19 |    include ::Turbo::Streams::ActionHelper
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

sorbet/rbi/dsl/rails/conductor/base_controller.rbi:22: Unable to resolve constant ActionHelper https://srb.help/5002
    22 |    include ::Turbo::Streams::ActionHelper
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

sorbet/rbi/dsl/rails/conductor/base_controller.rbi:22: Unable to resolve constant ActionHelper https://srb.help/5002
    22 |    include ::Turbo::Streams::ActionHelper
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

sorbet/rbi/dsl/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/incinerates_controller.rbi:19: Unable to resolve constant ActionHelper https://srb.help/5002
    19 |    include ::Turbo::Streams::ActionHelper
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

sorbet/rbi/dsl/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/incinerates_controller.rbi:19: Unable to resolve constant ActionHelper https://srb.help/5002
    19 |    include ::Turbo::Streams::ActionHelper
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Errors: 23
```

After applying a workaround for the Turbo issues described here (https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/issues/671), I'm left with issues related to .require method not found.

```
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48: Method permit does not exist on String component of T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters) https://srb.help/7003
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
                                    ^^^^^^
  Got T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters) originating from:
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48:
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Did you mean format? Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48: Replace with format
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
                                    ^^^^^^
    https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/c77e3a550a6bb9c1a0772fabf433d6763a86f33d/rbi/core/kernel.rbi#L1547: Defined here
    1547 |  def format(format, *args); end
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48: Method permit does not exist on Numeric component of T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters) https://srb.help/7003
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
                                    ^^^^^^
  Got T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters) originating from:
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48:
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Did you mean format? Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48: Replace with format
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
                                    ^^^^^^
    https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/c77e3a550a6bb9c1a0772fabf433d6763a86f33d/rbi/core/kernel.rbi#L1547: Defined here
    1547 |  def format(format, *args); end
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48: Method permit does not exist on T::Array[T.untyped] component of T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters) https://srb.help/7003
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
                                    ^^^^^^
  Got T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters) originating from:
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48:
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Did you mean format? Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48: Replace with format
    48 |    params.require(:person).permit(
                                    ^^^^^^
    https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/c77e3a550a6bb9c1a0772fabf433d6763a86f33d/rbi/core/kernel.rbi#L1547: Defined here
    1547 |  def format(format, *args); end
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Errors: 3
```

Is there anything missing? What is the proper way of doing this?

Note: workaround for the .permit issue can be found here https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/issues/1122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turbo ones are a known issue, you can take a look at https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/issues/671 for a workaround.

Comment: Thank you. That works for the turbo issue. I'm only left with the `.permit` missing after applying `.require` on `params`.

Comment: To fix the .permit issue, I had to apply the following workaround: https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/issues/1122